# How do I get the day of the week with NSCalendar?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to get the day of the week, preferable in an integer from 1 to 7... is this possible?

This is what I currently have to get the current hour, minute and second....

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger second = [dateComponents second];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =[gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:myDate];

NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

Or to integrate with the code you already have:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger weekday = [dateComponents weekday];
```

That will get you values 1 .. 7 where 1 is Sunday.

Hope that helps.